# How to use the same URL alias for all translations of a node?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I want to use the same URL alias for all nodes regardless of language.

On my site, the primary language is English.  Translation is enabled for nodes of type **basic page**.

At `/admin/config/regional/content-language`, content translation is enabled for the **Title** and **Body** fields.

With this configuration, on the node edit page, it shows "URL alias (all languages").  I set a URL alias manually for each English node.

However, when I add a translation in another language, even though I see my alias on the translation edit page, this alias is not applied for that language.  In other words, if the alias is *myfolder/mypage* in English, if I go to the Japanese translation at `/ja/myfolder/mypage`, I get a "page not found" error. Instead, the page is available at `/node/5` or whatever the NID is.  But, on the "edit node" page for the Japanese translation, it does show the English alias with the text "all languages."

**Workaround**

I can go to `/admin/config/regional/content-language` and enable translation of **URL alias** and then manually set each additional language alias to the English alias, but this seems like a lot of extra work to keep the same alias.

Comment: It looks like your problem is related to this Drupal core - path.module issue => [If you don't want to translate your URL alias, the original URL alias won't work with your translations](https://www.drupal.org/node/2689459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Rockabelly, this is a [bug with Drupal core.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2689459)  For now, there is a patch to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The [Neutral Paths module](https://www.drupal.org/project/neutral_paths) should work in this situation.  From the project page:

> A module for multi-language web sites, allowing users to access
>   content in languages other than the current one by using path aliases.